# "All Developers" and "All Views" screens are empty

Tags: sonarqube

I've installed Sonar 3.6 with both the Developer Cockpit and Views plugins. The Developer Cockpit seems to work fine since I can get the list of developers for a given project, see for example at bottom left of http://sonar.xwiki.org/dashboard/index/1

However when I click on Projects > All Developers, I get an empty page with the message "No Data": http://sonar.xwiki.org/all_projects?qualifier=DEV

The same happens when I click Projects > All Views, even though I have created a view.

The documentation says:
* "To compute all the views, run the following command: sonar-runner views"
* "To compute all the developers, run the following command: sonar-runner devcockpit"

However I have no idea if 1) this is the problem (since I can see devs on individual project page) and 2) how to run this. In our setup, we use the Jenkins Sonar plugin to run mvn sonar:sonar and we don't use any "sonar-runner" explicitly.

Any idea? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions of Views and DevCokpit require that you run the `sonar-runner views` and `sonar-runner devcockpit` commands to compute the views/devs. Running a Sonar analysis on a project is not enough.

With the latest version of the Jenkins Sonar plugin, you can run those 2 computation tasks by defining dedicated jobs (one for views and one for devcockpit) that will trigger a [SonarQube Runner execution](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonarQubeonJenkinsJob-TriggeringaTaskwiththeSonarQubeRunner) - which has a dedicated field to tell which task to pass ("views" or "devcockpit").

Comment: Great! For the record, we'll update the documentation ASAP on this.

Comment: Hi Vincent Massol can you please describe how you made developer cockpit work through jenkins? I'm facing the same problem. The details at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonarQubeonJenkinsJob-TriggeringaTaskwiththeSonarQubeRunner was not descriptive enough or am I missing something here?

Comment: When I run the build putting the task as devcockpit, it says, "No task found for command: devcockpit" Is there anything more I have to provide for the build?